# Modify localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm using simplecartjs to power an online store. It stores it's data in local storage, which looks like this:

```
{"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":20,"name":"Mattamusta -teippi","size":"Tyhjä"},"SCI-3":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-3","price":19,"name":"Mohawk .vaimennusmatto 48 x 39cm"},"SCI-5":{"quantity":2,"id":"SCI-5","price":8,"name":"Car Speaker -hajuste","color":"Green Tea"},"SCI-7":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-7","price":50,"name":"Asennuspaketti"},"SCI-9":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-9","price":30,"name":"Quartz-kalvot","color":"Yellow","size":"50cm x 30cm"},"SCI-11":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-11","price":30,"name":"Quartz-kalvot","color":"True Blue","size":"50cm x 30cm"}}
```

And I want to add this line **before** it's closed.

```
"SCI-12":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-12","price":5,"name":"Toimituskulut"}
```

However, the amount of products will depend on user, and so on **SCI-12** must grow with the number of items.

**EDIT** Actually, it doens't have to use **SCI-1**, it can be anything, as long as it's after the items.

**EDIT2**
Here's what I'm trying... But without luck.

```
$("#matkahuolto").click(function(){
    var value_object = '"Toimituskulut":{"quantity":1,"id":"Toimituskulut","price":5,"name":"Toimituskulut"}';
    var json_object = JSON.parse(localStorage.your_json); // convert string to object

    json_object["simpleCart_items"] = value_object; // add value

    localStorage.your_json = JSON.stringify(json_object);  // store it again.

    });

    $("#posti").click(function(){
    var json_object = JSON.parse(localStorage.your_json); // convert string to object

    json_object["simpleCart_items"] = value_object; // add value

    localStorage.your_json = JSON.stringify(json_object);  // store it again.

    });
```

**EDIT3** A screenshot of localstorage.
[image: LocalStorage]

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that. Odd it is then, as I want it to be displayed as another product.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would say after. The whole local storage is a mystery for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is how items are stored in [localStorage](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/), which is basically like a hashmap/dictionary in that the items are stored in key value pairs.

For example to store a `string` `localStorage` you would do something like

```
localStorage["myKey"] = "some value";
```

To retrieve the value you would just to the reverse

```
var myValue = localStorage["myKey"];
```

The next thing to realize is that you can in fact *only* store strings in localStorage, so if you want to store a object you need to first convert it to a string representation. This is usually done by converting the object to [JSON](http://www.json.org/) which is a compact notation used to represent an object as a string. To convert an object to JSON you just use the `JSON.stringify` method, and to parse an item you use the `JSON.parse` method

For example to convert an object to JSON

```
var someObject = {id: 1, name: 'Test'};

var jsonSomeObject = JSON.stringify(someObject); 
// jsonSomeObject looks like "{"id":1,"name":"test"}"
```

And to read an object from JSON

```
someObject = JSON.parse(jsonSomeObject);
```

So now in your case assuming that your object contains the appropriate data all you need to do is `stringify` your object and add it to `localStorage` using some key,

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({"SCI-12":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-12","price":5,"name":"Toimituskulut"}});

localStorage["aKey"] = jsonData;
```

and when you want to access this data later (presumably after coming back to the page)

```
var mySCI = JSON.parse(localStorage["aKey"])
```

If you are trying to update a specific entry in localStorage then you would just read it in and then overwrite it, for example

```
var mySCI = JSON.parse(localStorage["aKey"]);
mySCI.SCI-12.quantity = 2;
localStorage["aKey"] = JSON.stringify(mySCI);
```

Keep in mind that while most browsers have built in support for JSON some older ones don't, if this is an issue you can include Douglass Crockfords [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) script to provide support.

**Edit:**

Based on the screenshot you just posted, you can see that the key under which the values are stored in localStorage is in fact simpleCart_items (and not your_json which are using in your code), and that the object that is being stored has a object stored under the key "SCI-1) (and probably others under "SCI's"). So what you would need to do is something like the following

```
 $("#matkahuolto").click(function(){
    var value_object = {quantity: 1, id: 1, name: "someName"} ; 
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(localStorage["simpleCart_items"]);
    json_object["SCI_1"] = value_object; // add value

 localStorage["simpleCart_items"] = JSON.stringify(json_object);  // store it again.

});

$("#posti").click(function(){
 // convert string to object
 var json_object = JSON.parse(localStorage["simpleCart_items"]); 

json_object["SCI-1"] = value_object; // add value

 localStorage["simpleCart_items"] = JSON.stringify(json_object);  // store it again.

});
```

Comment: So, if I understand correcly, when I look at local storage, it has a key called `simpleCart_items` and a value of `{"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":20,"name":"Valkoinen hiilikuitu -teippi","size":"Tyhjä"}}`. So I have to retrieve the value before modifying it, and add the data I want?

Comment: Not quite, from the code you provided your accessing a key *your_json* and in that object there is a key *simpleCart_items*, I edited my answer based on this. If this isn't the right key you will need to modify your code accordingly.

Comment: your code has the right values, but the local storage looks the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you sure you are accessing the right key in your localstorage?

Comment: I think you meant you updated your *question*. Anyway I updated my anwser based on your edit.

Comment: Oops, yeah, that's what I meant. I'll try this now.

Comment: Seems to be working, however this is a **bit** out of my understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

LocalStorage stores all data as as string of text.  So it would be easiest to modify it before it has been converted to a string of text.

Otherwise you need to pull the json string into an object, add the property, convert it back to a string and store it.

**Sample Code**

```
var json_object = JSON.parse(localStorage.your_json); // convert string to object
json_object[key] = value_object; // add value
localStorage.your_json = JSON.stringify(json_object);  // store it again.
```

**Note**

This is what indexedDB is for.
One might want to consider this as a substitute.

Comment: @pure_code Why do you always delete your comments? All that does is confuse people because they can't see your conversation