# How can I use localStorage to remember which classes were set on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm going to use [Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) so when a user presses Alt+L it uses jQuery and adds the class `light` to body tag, I'd also like it to remove the class once Alt+L is pressed.

How can I add localstorage to remember if there is class `light`?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I can do add the class using the keyboard shortcut just fine, it's just I've never used localstorage and I've found it confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't provide the code because it's so simple that I don't need to. Instead, I will provide you guidance to use **documentation** which will give you answers to the api's you request information about.

`localStorage` is incredibly straight forward. It's a simple key/value store.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developr.mozilla.org/en-US/) will provide you information on what api's do and how they work (with working examples).

I'd also like to mention, that there is likely questions about `localStorage` on StackOverflow already. Here is a post on StackOverflow - [Modify localstorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412217/modify-localstorage)

Welcome.

---

To match the OP's REAL question, "How can I use localStorage to remember which classes were set on an element".

```
var $body = $("body");

// On ALT+L event
if ($body.hasClass("light")) {
    $body.addClass("light");
    window.localStorage.hasLightClass = true;
} else {
    window.localStorage.hasLightClass = false;
    $body.removeClass("light");
}

// On page load
var hasClass = window.localStorage.hasLightClass || false;
if (JSON.parse(hasClass)) {
  $body.addClass("light");
}
```

Comment: Have you looked through StackOverflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412217/modify-localstorage

Comment: They're trying to store a load of JSON, I'm only looking to store a class name and apply it or remove it when the user hits the keyboard shortcut

Comment: Right, but it shows how to use `localStorage`. Is your problem more directed towards how your code remembers if a specific element had a class or not instead of how `localStorage` works or both?

Comment: It's not how localStorage works, it's how I can add a class using jQuery and then using localStorage to remember it

Comment: Okay, your question seems more like, "How does `localStorage` work.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean it to be like it. It was suppose to be more how can I do this

Comment: Does this look closer to what you want? I didn't test it but it's the main idea.

Comment: Yeh, that looks fine. I'm gonna play around with the code, thanks!