# Editable jQuery grid to store data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grid

I am looking for a jQuery grid that will allow me to edit data and save it so it will be available for viewing every time I open the document with the data.

Any recommendations? The simpler the better. I am just trying to create a new document with a grid to replace an old Google Spreadsheet that I currently use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you Looking for [slickgrid](http://mathankumar.drupalgardens.com/blog/best-jquery-editable-grid-plugin-slickgrid)?

And its not possible to see eachtime time without persisting the `data.`

And [DataGrid](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php) is here with Basic CRUD operations.

Comment: Here's an example of this: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html

Comment: @Xymostech That looks exactly what I am looking for! Do you know how to save the changes?

Comment: @randomizertech you have to use AJAX for that to persist the data.

Comment: @Baadshah any examples so I can understand better?

Comment: @randomizertech Maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12414343/57318 It's an example of using localStorage (so, client-side browser storage).

Comment: Here you go with another  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674669/slickgrid-save-all-data-at-once

Comment: @Baadshah the first one seems to be very simple but I cannot get it to work. Once I click the Save form button, it just brings me a blank grid

Comment: @Xymostech it seems like a good solution, but would this be viewable for everyone accessing the website since it's using localStorage?

Comment: @randomizertech Ah, no it would not. Then you'll have to do something more complex.

Comment: For that you have to save on server to serve multiple users.

Comment: @Baadshah how would I do that? I just want to do this as simple as possible

Comment: Sorry to say.. not that much simple.at least you need design a simple client server implementation, which all webapplications do.

Comment: You can google it like saving data in db using ajax..right now not possible to browse through tabs..am on mobile. :( .